# allow someone to see private github repo w/o ability to affect the repo

Tags: github

Hi I'm trying to let someone see private repo code but dont want to make my repo public and dont want them to have the ability to change stuff. Is this possible? I looked in the "admin" section of the site and didn't find anything suitable. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can only do this when you have set up an Organisation, where you can assign teams different accesses to different repositories. If you only have standard private repositories, you can only give someone read / write access.